# React useEffect causing infinite loop even when dependencies are listed (with Firebase realtime database)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, loops, react-hooks, infinite

I've been trying to solve this but no matter what solution I do, it is still stuck in a infinite loop.

Here is the code

```
    const [carr, setCarr] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
    sortedRosterCollection.once('value', (snap) => {
        snap.forEach((doc) =>{
            if (doc.key==="Carr Intermediate"){
                var school = doc.key;
                var mentorList = doc.val();
                var schoolMentor = {school:school, mentors: mentorList};
                setCarr(schoolMentor)
                console.log(carr)
            }
        });
    });

},[carr]);
```

No matter what I do "console.log(carr)" is fired endlessly.

Comment: You set the `carr` value inside the same useEffect that's triggered when `carr` is changed, causing an infinite loop.  Don't see why you need to have it in the dependency list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inspect the value of `carr` whenever it's changed, put it into another use effect:

```
const [carr, setCarr] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
  sortedRosterCollection.once('value', (snap) => {
    snap.forEach((doc) => {
      if (doc.key === "Carr Intermediate") {
        var school = doc.key;
        var mentorList = doc.val();
        var schoolMentor = {
          school: school,
          mentors: mentorList
        };
        setCarr(schoolMentor)
      }
    });
  });

}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(carr)
}, [carr])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't forget cleanup function in useEffect hook like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  effect
  return () => {
    cleanup
  }
}, [input])
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to make this problem like you because useEffect can compare two object.
You can make the reference to the link: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/comparing-objects-in-javascript-ce2dc1f3de7f. And I check changed by using below code:

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```